# Is ioctl()'s FIONREAD on a C socket reliable?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm seeing strange behavior with the following piece of code:

```
int len;
ioctl(conn_fd, FIONREAD, &len);
```

The usual code you might imagine precedes this (it's a toy web server):

```
...
int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
listen(sock_fd, 5);
int conn_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addr_size);
```

The unusual behavior is when I use curl to make a request to my toy web server, everything works perfect and `len` is the exact size of the request. When I use Chrome, Postman, or wget, `len` is 0. Because `len` is 0, my code treats it as an empty response and doesn't consume the request.

To verify there is actually data (besides the fact that curl works), I follow the code up with:

```
char full_request[16384];
int bytes_read = read(conn_fd, full_request, 16383);
```

To my delight, outputting full_request gives me, well, the full request no matter if it's curl, Chrome, Postman, or wget.

What gives? Is my call to `ioctl` not to be trusted? Is there a better way to know the size of the data coming in so I can consume it?

EDIT for EJP:

```
 char *full_request = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
 *full_request = '\0';

 for (;;) {
     char buf[64];
     int bytes_read;
     int new_len;

     bytes_read = recv(conn_fd, buf, 63, 0);
     buf[bytes_read] = '\0';

     if (bytes_read <= 0) break;

     new_len = strlen(full_request) + bytes_read + 1;

     full_request = realloc(full_request, new_len * sizeof(char));
     strcat(full_request, buf);
 }
```

Comment: Actually, when `read` or `recv` returns `0`, that means the connection was closed in a nice way (with e.g. `close` or `closesocket`) by the other end.

Comment: The only time I get it to return 0 is when I cancel the request on the client end. Otherwise it just blocks on `read` or `recv`.

Comment: `len` is not the size of the incoming request; it's how much data is available for reading *right now*. If no data has been received from the browser yet, it may be 0. If not all of the data has been received yet, it may be less than what's available to `read` (which is called slightly later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your reasoning is that `read()` blocks until data *is* available, or end of stream or an error occurs. So the fact that it did return data doesn't indicate that FIONREAD was wrong at the moment you called it. There is rarely a good reason to use FIONREAD.

You also cannot rely on a single read returning the full request. It is only obliged to transfer at least one byte. You have to loop.

Comment: I put an edit for you. I did have a loop, but it always just blocks when it's done. When I cancel the request on the client side, it exits my loop and I see the full request is available.

Comment: @brian For HTTP you have to parse the request. First read all headers, then (if there's a body), consume it according to `Content-Length`.

Comment: @brian If you're implementing HTTP you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors, especially the parts about Content-length and Transfer-encoding. You can't just wing it like this.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I definitely have some reading to do. Once I'm done I'll see if this is still a problem for me.